# Access element and its count in a collection

Tags: python

```
>>> import collections, re
>>> texts = ['John likes to watch movies. Mary likes too.', 'John also likes to watch football games.']
>>> bagsofwords = [ collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', txt)) for txt in texts]
>>> bagsofwords[0]
Counter({'likes': 2, 'watch': 1, 'Mary': 1, 'movies': 1, 'John': 1, 'to': 1, 'too': 1})
>>> bagsofwords[1]
Counter({'watch': 1, 'games': 1, 'to': 1, 'likes': 1, 'also': 1, 'John': 1, 'football': 1})
>>> sumbags = sum(bagsofwords, collections.Counter())
>>> sumbags
Counter({'likes': 3, 'watch': 2, 'John': 2, 'to': 2, 'games': 1, 'football': 1, 'Mary': 1, 'movies': 1, 'also': 1, 'too': 1})
>>>
```

For the `bagsofwords[0]`, is it possible to access the string `"likes"` and its count?

Comment: `bagsofwords[0]['likes']`

Comment: I was planning to display bagsofwords[0] in a more table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest method would be,

```
dictofwords = dict(bagsofwords[0])
for word, count in dictofwords.iteritems():
    print word, count
```

> **Output:**
>   movies 1
>   watch 1
>   to 1
>   likes 2
>   likes 2
>   John 1
>   Mary 1
>   too 1

### Using Counter methods

You can iterate over a Counter as follows.

```
for i in bagsofwords[0].elements():
    print i, bagsofwords[0][i]
```

> **Output:**
>   movies 1
>   watch 1
>   to 1
>   likes 2
>   likes 2
>   John 1
>   Mary 1
>   too 1

Counter has got an inbuilt method called `most_common()` Using that you can get it in sorted form.

```
for i in bagsofwords[0].most_common():
    print i[0], i[1]
```

> **Output:**
>   likes 2
>   movies 1
>   watch 1
>   to 1
>   John 1
>   Mary 1
>   too 1

---

Hope it helps! :)